SQL Server stored procedure not returning the values to ESQL List
I am migrating my underlying database from Sybase to SQL Server. The ESQL code which was working on Sybase is not working on SQL Server.
Basically I am trying to call a stored procedure from an ESQL function. This stored procedure returns some columns with values which I am trying to collect in a ESQL list. But this list is not able to collect the values once the stored procedure call is completed.
Here's my code for calling a ESQL function:
while I < n
Declare MyList reference to Environment.XMLNSC.MyData.LIST[I];
Create Field Enviornment.XMLNSC.MyData.LIST[I].GetParams;

Call MyParamsFunctionESQL (MyList, Enviornment.XMLNSC.MyData.LIST[I]GetParams);

//Here's is the definition of MyParams Funcion

Create Procedure MyParamsFunctionESQL (In List1 Reference, In Params)
Begin
Declare Value1, Value2 Integer;

Set Value1 = CAST(List1.Value1 AS Integer);
Set Value2 = CAST(List1.Value2 AS Integer);

//Here's the call for DB stored procedure functon
Call MyParamsFunction(Value1, Value2, Params.GetMyParams[]) IN database.(getDNS("MyDSN")).dbo
END;

// Here's the definition for the stored procedure 

Create Procedure MyParamsFunction
(
IN Value1 Integer;
IN Value2 Integer;
) Language Database
Dynamic Result Set 1
External Name "dbo.MyParamsFunction"

I am expecting that after the stored procedure call, the values returned by the stored procedure should be collected in the list GetMyParams[], but I am not getting the values in that list

You don't tell us what error message(s) you're getting, but I imagine getDNS("MyDSN") probably isn't helping. Should that instead be getDSN("MyDSN")?

there is no error message I was expecting to a tree to be created with database result set in Params.GetMyParams i.e.; GetMyParams.Field1, GetMyParams.Field2. Database connection is all OK, and stored procedure is being executed from ESQL

I'm not expert in ESQL, but I'm guessing the above code gets transpiled to mssql dito and executed? Do you have the database definition of the procedure? And the exact calls being made? My guess is that this is a SET NOCOUNT ON; issue, but i've been wrong before :)

Have you tried to capture the query that is send to the database in the SSMS Profiler ?

SQL Server uses TSQL, so that syntax isn't valid.

How are you executins E-SQL on SQL Server?

@Charlieface : what is invalid syntax

Create Procedure MyParamsFunctionESQL (In List1 Reference, In Params) and Language Database Dynamic Result Set 1 are not TSQL
